# displaying number of search results on google results page

Tags: seo, google-search

How can I make google display the number of search results from my website on google search results page.

The highlight yellow shows the number of search results. How can I make it happen for my website as-well?

[image]

Comment: I think Google bots are smart enough to pick these things up if you have the amount of results listed. I would make sure you have your `rel=prev` and `rel=next` implemented correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function of the Structured Data markup schema. Go to your Google Webmaster tools profile and under Search Appearance you will find tools for data highlighting. The structured data markup can help you accomplish this in your sites code.

Comment: This is incorrect, there isn't an option to mark up such data using the Data Highlighter in Webmaster tools.